# Android Studio 2.2's incremental compiler can't see generated protobufs

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers, android-studio-2.2

I upgraded my stable version of Android Studio to 2.2 and now the IDE's "incremental compiler" can't find any of the symbols for generated protobuf classes.  I open the project and it can build and deploy the app to a device just fine.  But when I open a Java class file that contains generated protobuf references, Android Studio marks them as errors soon after the file opens.  Every Java import of a generated proto class is marked with "Cannot resolve symbol".

I [first noticed](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/92) this a month ago on the canary channel but didn't think anything of it because I was floundering with other protobuf issues (upgrading to 3.0.0 with its javalite split).  I forgot about it until today.  It's still possible to work on the project, it's just that the IDE is near useless since it thinks there are errors (even though real compiles are fine with it).

For reference.

```
gradle-2.14.1
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0
com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.0
com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0
com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0
```

And in the modules that contain .proto files:

```
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = google_protoc_artifact
    }
    plugins {
        javalite {
            artifact = google_protoc_javalite_artifact
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                remove java
            }
            task.plugins {
                javalite { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue and found out the following:

1) In order for idea (studio) to see your source, you need to help it by adding the idea plugin to your module:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        // Use "${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/javalite" for LITE_RUNTIME protos
        sourceDirs += file("${protobuf.generatedFilesBaseDir}/main/java");
    }
}
```

2) Another bug, Android Studio seems to ignore any source directory under build/. You have to move your generated directory outside of build:

```
protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
}
```

These two changes fixed the problem introduced by Android Studio 2.2 for us.

Comment: That did the trick! I make use of the javalite API so I made a note of that in your answer (the directories are different).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the kotlin protobuf plugin and to fix the error of the IDE not being able to resolve it. I tweaked the other answer above to point to the main folder.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    idea
}

idea {
    module {
        // explicitly tell intellij where to resolve generated proto files
        sourceDirs.plusAssign(file("build/generated/source/proto/main/"))
    }
}
```